# Adding up string length from SQL array

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to add up the character length from an inserted URL. I have grabbed all the selected URLs from the database in an array and am trying to add them up in a foreach function.

```
function countLen($email) {

    $countLen = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE user='$email'");
    $resultLen = mysql_result($countLen, 0);

    foreach($resultLen as &$string) {


        $length = strlen($string);
        $totallen = ($totallen + $length);

        return $totallen;




    }





}
```

Comment: You appear to be returning from inside the foreach. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: You need to move your return statement outside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just do it all the summing in SQL:

```
function countLen($email)
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(LENGTH(url)) as 'sum' FROM urls WHERE user='$email'");
    return current(mysql_fetch_array($res));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$total = 0;

$res = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE user='$email'");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
{
  $total += strlen( $row['url'] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return should be out side the loop.. like

```
function countLen($email) {

  $countLen = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE user='$email'");
  $resultLen = mysql_result($countLen, 0);
  $totallen = 0;
  foreach($resultLen as &$string) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    $totallen = ($length + $totallen);
  }
  return $totallen;
}
```